# multiDexKeepFile not working

Tags: android, android-build, android-multidex

We are having problems in building our multidex App. We keep receiving different `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` erros during the application boot.

We noticed that they are very likely related to the multidex issues. As the required classes for booting the App must be present in the primary DEX file and they are not being included in the `classes.dex`. We performed the steps described in https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#keep
but the classes we specify in the `multidex-config.txt`, or even in the `multidex-config.pro` are not being placed in the primary dex file (`classes.dex`).

Do you guys have experience using the `multiDexKeepFile` or the multiDexKeepProguard? Does it really work? Is there any trick to make it work and place the files in the `classes.dex`?

Comment: Hi Nadilson, did you get it to work?

Comment: Same question as Thomas Wanschik

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: No. I found some info point out that it was a known bug in the build tools.

Comment: @NadilsonFerreira Two years later, the bug is still there for me. How did you deal with it?

Answer (score 3):

Try updating your gradle plugin. I've seen that in `2.2.0` the configuration is ignored entirely.  When I updated to `2.3.3` it started respecting the rules I set.

Example:

```
classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3
```

And in my default config I have this set:

```
    multiDexEnabled true
    multiDexKeepProguard file('proguard.multidex.config')
```

Also you may have to do a clean build before the changes are reflected.

Comment: I'm using the (current) latest gradle plugin version - `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'`, but am still having the OP's problem. Also, by inspecting my apk ( https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer ), I see the classes I have specified via `multiDexKeepFeel` are present in **classes2.dex** rather than in the *primary* dex file, **classes.dex**.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.And i still don't know why.
But i found another solution,and it works.
In your app module's build.gradle add dexOptions:

```java
android {
    dexOptions {
        additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex',
                                '--set-max-idx-number=60000',
                                '--main-dex-list='+projectDir+'/your_multidexconfig.txt',
                                '--minimal-main-dex'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that these parameters are for dx, not d8. Of these only --main-dex-list is available for d8.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your `minSdkVersion`, if your `minSdkVersion` is >= 21, `multiDexKeepProguard` is not supported. Because the build tools has do the dex split by default.

More details:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex