# ClassNotFoundException when specifying custom IME as EditText's android:inputMethod value

Tags: android, android-input-method

My app includes a custom IME, **MyCustomIME**. It works fine when the user manually selects it as the device's input method.

However, when I try to specify MyCustomIME as the input method for an EditText within my **EnterPinActivity**'s layout file:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pinEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:inputMethod="com.example.MyCustomIME"
    android:maxLength="4" />
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.EnterPinActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class EditText
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class EditText
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.example.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:365)
    at com.example.EnterPinActivity.onCreate(EnterPinActivity.java:37)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MyCustomIME
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1616)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:88)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:84)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:73)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:69)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:197)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:115)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
    at com.example.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:365) 
    at com.example.EnterPinActivity.onCreate(EnterPinActivity.java:37) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MyCustomIME
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1614)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:88) 
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:84) 
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:73) 
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:69) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:197) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:115) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
    at com.example.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:365) 
    at com.example.EnterPinActivity.onCreate(EnterPinActivity.java:37) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.MyCustomIME" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309) 
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273) 
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1614) 
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:88) 
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:84) 
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:73) 
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:69) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:197) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:115) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
    at com.example.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:365) 
    at com.example.EnterPinActivity.onCreate(EnterPinActivity.java:37) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MyCustomIME
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:
```

This is how MyCustomIME appears in my manifest:

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example">

    ...

    <application
            android:name=".MyApplication"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_2"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        ...

        <service
            android:name=".MyCustomIME"
            android:label="@string/my_custom_keyboard"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.view.im"
                android:resource="@xml/keyboard_method" />
        </service>

        ...

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication. And, for completeness, this is the MyCustomIME class:

```
package com.example;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard.Key;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodSubtype;
import java.util.List;

public class MyCustomIME extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private static final String TAG = MyCustomIME.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String MODE_DECIMAL = "decimal";
    private static final String MODE_NUMERIC = "numeric";
    private static final String MODE_QWERTY = "qwerty";
    private static final int KEY_CODE_SWITCH_KEYBOARD = 1111;
    private static final int KEY_CODE_BACKSPACE = -5;

    private KeyboardView keyboardView;
    private Keyboard keyboard;
    private boolean caps = false;
    private boolean capWords = false;

    @Override @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    public View onCreateInputView() {

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateInputView()");

        keyboardView = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
        InputMethodSubtype currentInputMethodSubtype = getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
        if (currentInputMethodSubtype != null) {
            mySetKeyboard(currentInputMethodSubtype);
        }

        return keyboardView;
    }

    private void mySetKeyboard(InputMethodSubtype inputMethodSubtype) {

        String mode = inputMethodSubtype.getMode();

        if (mode.equals(MODE_DECIMAL)) {
            keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard_decimal);
        }
        else if (mode.equals(MODE_NUMERIC)) {
            keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard_numeric);
        }
        else {
            keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard_qwerty);
        }

        keyboard.setShifted(caps);

        InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imeManager != null) {
            IBinder imeToken = getImeToken();
            boolean shouldOfferSwitchingToNextInputMethod = imeManager.shouldOfferSwitchingToNextInputMethod(imeToken);
            if (!shouldOfferSwitchingToNextInputMethod) {

                // Hide the switch key
                int switchKeyWidth = 0;
                List<Key> keys = keyboard.getKeys();
                for (Key key : keys) {
                    if (key.codes[0] == KEY_CODE_SWITCH_KEYBOARD) {
                        switchKeyWidth = key.width;
                        key.width = 0;
                        key.icon = null;
                        key.iconPreview = null;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Make the BACKSPACE button bigger
                for (Key key : keys) {
                    if (key.codes[0] == KEY_CODE_BACKSPACE) {
                        key.width += switchKeyWidth;// + key.gap;
                        key.edgeFlags = Keyboard.EDGE_RIGHT;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    }

    private InputMethodSubtype getCurrentInputMethodSubtype() {

        InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imeManager != null) {
            return imeManager.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private IBinder getImeToken() {

        Window window = getWindow().getWindow();
        if (window != null) {
            return window.getAttributes().token;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void setInputMethodAndSubtype(String inputMethodId, InputMethodSubtype inputMethodSubtype) {

        IBinder imeToken = getImeToken();
        if (imeToken != null) {
            InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (imeManager != null) {
                imeManager.setInputMethodAndSubtype(imeToken, inputMethodId, inputMethodSubtype);
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not set setInputMethodAndSubtype as imeManager == null");
                Utilities.makeToast(this, "Could not set setInputMethodAndSubtype as imeManager == null");
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not set setInputMethodAndSubtype as imeToken == null");
            Utilities.makeToast(this, "Could not set setInputMethodAndSubtype as imeToken == null");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCurrentInputMethodSubtypeChanged(InputMethodSubtype newInputMethodSubtype) {

        if (keyboardView != null) {
            mySetKeyboard(newInputMethodSubtype);
        }
        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not setKeyboard as keyboardView == null");
            Utilities.makeToast(this, "Could not setKeyboard as keyboardView == null");
        }
        //super.onCurrentInputMethodSubtypeChanged(newInputMethodSubtype);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo editorInfo, boolean restarting) {

        int editTextInputType = editorInfo.inputType;
        Log.d(TAG, "editTextInputType: " + editTextInputType);

        int inputTypeMaskClass = editTextInputType & InputType.TYPE_MASK_CLASS;
        boolean isEditTextInputTypeNumber = inputTypeMaskClass == InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;

        int inputTypeMaskFlags = editTextInputType & InputType.TYPE_MASK_FLAGS;
        boolean isEditTextInputTypeDecimal = inputTypeMaskFlags == InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL;

        //caps = editorInfo.initialCapsMode != 0;
        caps = inputTypeMaskFlags == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS
//            || inputTypeMaskFlags == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS
//            || inputTypeMaskFlags == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES
        ;

        capWords = inputTypeMaskFlags == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS;

        InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imeManager != null) {
            final List<InputMethodInfo> enabledImis = imeManager.getEnabledInputMethodList();
            for (InputMethodInfo imi : enabledImis) {

                String serviceName = imi.getServiceName();
                Log.d(TAG, "serviceName: " + serviceName);

                String imiId = imi.getId();
                Log.d(TAG, "imiId: " + imiId);

                if (serviceName.endsWith(TAG)) { // If it's our custom keyboard

                    List<InputMethodSubtype> inputMethodSubtypes = imeManager.getEnabledInputMethodSubtypeList(imi,
                            true // allowsImplicitlySelectedSubtypes
                    );

                    // For each of our "qwerty", "numeric" and "decimal" subTypes.
                    for (InputMethodSubtype inputMethodSubtype : inputMethodSubtypes) {

                        String keyboardMode = inputMethodSubtype.getMode();

                        if (isEditTextInputTypeNumber) {

                            if (isEditTextInputTypeDecimal) {

                                if (keyboardMode.equals(MODE_DECIMAL)) {

                                    setInputMethodAndSubtype(imiId, inputMethodSubtype);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            else {

                                if (keyboardMode.equals(MODE_NUMERIC)) {

                                    setInputMethodAndSubtype(imiId, inputMethodSubtype);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {

                            if (keyboardMode.equals(MODE_QWERTY)) {

                                setInputMethodAndSubtype(imiId, inputMethodSubtype);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        super.onStartInputView(editorInfo, restarting);
    }

    private void playClick(int keyCode){
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager != null) {

            switch (keyCode) {

                case 32:

                    audioManager.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
                    break;

                case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
                case 10:

                    audioManager.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
                    break;

                case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:

                    audioManager.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
                    break;

                default:

                    audioManager.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {

        InputConnection inputConnection = getCurrentInputConnection();
        playClick(primaryCode);
        switch(primaryCode){

            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:

                inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
                break;

            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:

                caps = !caps;
                Log.d(TAG, "2. caps set to " + caps);
                keyboard.setShifted(caps);
                keyboardView.invalidateAllKeys();
                break;

            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:

                inputConnection.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
                break;

            case KEY_CODE_SWITCH_KEYBOARD:

                InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (imeManager != null) {
                    imeManager.switchToNextInputMethod(getImeToken(),
                            true // onlyCurrentIme
                    );
                }
                break;

            default:

                char code = (char)primaryCode;
                if(Character.isLetter(code) && caps){
                    code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
                }
                inputConnection.commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {
    }
}
```

What I've tried:

- Cleaning the project
- Turning off proguard
- Renaming the MyCustomIME to MyCustomIME2
- Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Uninstall and re-install app

but the problem remains. Any ideas?

Comment: If early in your app, you create an instance of `MyCustomIME` yourself via the constructor, does creating that instance succeed, and does it somehow cause your `EditText` inflation to work? If yes, then this might be a multidex problem. Creating instances of services ourselves is generally pointless, since the service isn't wired into the framework, but it might be a useful test to determine why that class is not being found.

Comment: I can create an instance of `MyCustomIME` fine in the `onCreate()` method of `MyApplication`, but the layout still won't inflate when the user reaches the EnterPinActivity. `MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication` (in order to solve some other problem from way back), so do you know what I could try next?

Comment: I haven't had to fuss much with Multidex, as for my cases if I need it usually "it just works". Try [this stuff](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#keep) for ensuring that your `MyCustomIME` class is in the primary DEX file, and see if that helps.

Comment: I've just followed those steps, setting the content of **multidex-config.txt** (which I've co-located with the **app/build.gradle** file) as `com/example/MyCustomIME.class`, but I still have the same problem. I've analysed the apk file ( https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer ) and it is showing that MyCustomIME resides in **classes2.dex**, which I presume isn't the primary dex file?

Comment: I would assume that `classes.dex` is the primary DEX file, though you're pretty much at my boundaries of my multidex knowledge.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. Same problem (currently, with no solution) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43905076/multidexkeepfile-not-working